# Why can't I mine the center of some larger ore pillars?

Tags: ps4, no-mans-sky

As I'm exploring planets and come across some of the larger ore pillars, I'm finding that they have an indestructible core. I can clear maybe 2/3 the radius of the mineral, then nothing more. If I put my cursor over it, it will identify the ore correctly - but the mining beam will only cause rocky chunks to fall off without destroying anything, and the ore's durability meter won't decrease.

Is this a glitch? An oversight on the part of the developers? Or is there some enhancement that will let me mine this later? I'm about 7 systems in and haven't found anything that would let me mine it.

Comment: A slight work-around, if the glitch isn't what I think it is: Use a Plasma Grenade to destroy the remaining material.

Comment: I also experienced this for the first time tonight.  I found a *giant* pillar of emeril that extended about 4x its above-ground height into the soil.  I mined about 1000 Em from it, but an irregularly shaped core (about 25% of the total volume) was left standing when I was done.  Despite the mining prompt popping up all over its surface, no amount of lasering or grenades could put a dent in what was left behind.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, this is a glitch. For the smaller pillars, you usually won't find this, and same for the medium-sized ones. The glitch is this; there are certain parts of the pillar that are not counted as part of the ore. This results in it being registered as a piece of ground, however, it is still part of the pillar, so you can "mine" it. You won't receive any resources from this, and it won't destroy the ore in the game.

When this occurs above-ground, you can destroy the 'core' by throwing plasma grenades at it with L1. However, if it occurs below the minimum plasma-grenade height (not too sure what this is, usually about 15 grenades below ground level), it will **not** be mineable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found another one of these pillars last night, but I wasn't able to destroy the 'core' with plasma grenades either.

Comment: @CodeMoose Was it above-ground?

Comment: it was indeed - a giant pillar of Emeril that extended up probably 3x my max jetpack height